# How can we write a unit test for printing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, unit-testing, printing

How can we write a unit test for printing?
for example visibility item on printing:

```
display: none;
```

Can we emulate print mode?

Comment: Don't know if it is possible, but you can emulate print in DevTools in Chrome. So for testing this may be an option in the testing framework you are using?

Comment: enzyme, jest use for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use iframe for printing and added some param to url for that. We can test printing using thit param:

```
window.location.hash = '?printMode=true'; // my variant
```

after that run component and lets try to write tests.

Please, check this answer:
[can we emulate print mode (media query print) for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219643/can-we-emulate-print-mode-media-query-print-for-unit-testing/48662155#48662155)