# can we emulate print mode (media query print) for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

can we emulate print mode (media query print) for unit testing?
(Ract, enzyme, jest) i try:

```
window.matchMedia('print')
```

but it does not work for me, style media print not applied;

Comment: can you add more code to your question please ?

Comment: for example I have a header on the page, on printing (@media print) header have style display: none
how I can write unit test for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use iframe for printing and added some param to url for that.
We can test printing using thit param:

```
window.location.hash = '?printMode=true'; // my variant
```

after that run component and lets try to write tests.